# List of EU banks that received state aid

Tags: banking, financial-crises

Is there a list of EU banks that got state aid / bailed out since 2008 crisis? I know EU state aid commission approves the fundings to banks, but does anyone keep track of which banks are tapping into these aids?

Comment: I heard that banks occasionally received emergency bailouts in the UK on multiple occasions over many decades before the crisis, but this would happen without any publicity. I posted a freeedon-of-information-request to the UK government asking for a list of these occasions but they made feeble excuses to avoid answering my question.

Answer (score 8):

[Pro Publica](http://www.propublica.org/) keeps an ongoing [list of bailout recipients in the United States](http://projects.propublica.org/bailout/list).

Here is a report on the UK bailouts during the crisis:
[The Comptroller and Auditor General’s Report on Accounts to the House of Commons: The financial stability interventions](http://www.nao.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/HMT_account_2010_2011.pdf)

The [SoFFin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoFFin) Wikipedia page has a list of participating German institutions.

[FACTBOX - Bank bailouts around the world covers a few additional countries's bailouts](http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/02/11/uk-financial-banks-bailouts-sb-idUSTRE51A5NO20090211) between September 2008 and February 2009. [A further update came in April of 2009](http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/04/09/us-hyporealestate-offer-bailouts-factbox-idUSTRE53822E20090409) but it doesn't seem exhaustive.

Page 28 of [Stability Programme of the Netherlands April 2011 Update](http://ec.europa.eu/europe2020/pdf/nrp/sp_netherlands_en.pdf) contains information on their biggest bailouts but I am unsure if it is exhaustive.

The [Spanish Fund for Orderly Bank Restructuring](http://www.frob.es/en/Paginas/Home.aspx) appears to be the key Spanish bailout program. The [FROB FAQ](http://www.scribd.com/doc/96543288/FROB-FAQ) lists entities receiving FROB support but again, this may not be exhaustive.

Comment: The list below also gives US companies. The main issues is getting the list out of US, ex Europe. http://money.cnn.com/news/specials/storysupplement/bankbailout/

Comment: Thanks. Somewhere in ECB pages information should be stored for the Spanish, Italian and recent Greek Bank injections. Not sure why it is not easily available. Are they hiding it :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://ec.europa.eu/competition/state_aid/register/) is a list of banks that received state aid during the financial crisis.